# What is the "easiest" way to find the number of dark pixels of a jpeg?

Tags: c++, image, image-processing, jpeg

I'm a first year engineering student and I'm working on a end of term project. Due to tight deadlines, I would like to avoid rummaging through image processing libraries. We (my group mates) need to find the easiest implementable method to *get an integer for the number of dark pixels from an image*. I have read many other posts regarding image processing, but they are much more complicated than we need. Is there an easy way to do this? It is important that it is easy because this is only a small part of our project and there can't be too much time committed to this.

As for languages, I would prefer to use C++.

On a side note, any exceptional help given would be cited in our report (just mention the name you want to be cited as and you'll go down in history). It would also give us time to sleep. Sleep is to engineering students what cake is to fat kids.

Comment: For each pixel in image, if pixel is dark darkpixels++

Comment: If you want quick and easy then use something like MATLAB (or free clone Octave). If it has to be C++ though then OpenCV will save you a lot of work.

Comment: The only way is: 1. Get the pixels (standard image-reading). 2. Classify them as dark or not according to your criteria. 3. Return the number of pixels classified "dark".

Comment: BTW I don't think the question is too broad. What's too broad about it?

Comment: @ddriver What's a _dark pixel_ actually?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - that's just a minor ambiguity. Obviously a threshold of some sort.

Comment: @ddriver Answer, or shut up?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - a dark pixels is one that is not a light pixel. Happy?

Comment: I am talking about a threshold

Comment: @ddriver As mentioned, answer this question concretely, if you think it isn't too broad.

Comment: How do you intend to read a jpg without using an image processing library?  From the spec?  ... really?

Comment: @Deduplicator I thought it wasn't as easy as getting the pixels from a jpeg image. I thought there is some kind of compression algorithm that jpeg uses which would make it difficult to simply get the pixels?

Comment: Which is why you use some library to read it for you (decompression included). There are myriad ones which can do it.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - done, see it can be answered even while keeping "dark pixel" a relative ambiguity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is it done in Qt (not image processing but application library)

```
#include <QImage>
#include <QColor>

uint countDarkPixels(QString filename, quint8 threshold) {
    QImage img(filename);
    uint darkPixels = 0;
    for (int x = 0; x < img.width(); ++x) {
        for (int y = 0; y < img.height(); ++y) {
            QColor color(img.pixel(x, y));
            if (color.toHsl().lightness() < threshold) darkPixels++;
        }
    }
   return darkPixels;
}
```

Works for other formats besides JPG too. It uses conversion to HSL which may not be very fast, but you said "easy" not "fast".

Comment: I did say that indeed. I will look into QImage and QColor as this seems very easily implementable; thanks for the time. Is there a name I can use for citing for the help?

Comment: Don't bother, I don't care about that. But you might want to switch the x and y iteration order, my example was done to be readable but it is not very CPU cache friendly, since it will iterate downward column at a time, iterating rows of pixels will likely be a lot faster.

Comment: This software is amazing and it can do everything. It's perfect for our robotics project!!!!

Comment: @Klik - Qt is a big framework and can certainly do a lot, although far from everything. And it isn't really suited for robots, it is an application framework, but it is very well featured, for example you can write professional software in C++ without using the C++ standard library at all, replacing it with Qt core classes.

Answer (score 1):

There are two stages to this:

- Load an image from a file.
- Determine how many pixels in that image are "dark".

The first stage isn't too difficult - you could either use a pre-existing library, such as [DevIL](http://openil.sourceforge.net/) or [FreeImage](http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/), or write your own - [this](http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/) and [this](http://www.martinreddy.net/gfx/2d-hi.html) should be enough to get you started.

Once you've loaded the image into your program somehow, you'll need to loop over the pixel data and count the number of "dark" pixels. Let's say you have an image structure that looks like this:

```
typedef struct
{

  int w;
  int h;
  unsigned char *data;

} image_s;
```

For simplicity, let's make the following assumptions:

- The image is stored in 24-bit, RGB format, so that each pixel is represented as three unsigned bytes like this: `RGBRGBRGB`.
- A "dark" pixel is one where `(R+G+B)/3 < 10`

Given the above, you would simply need to loop through each pixel within the image structure like so:

```
int count_dark_pixels(image_s *img)
{

  int dark_pixels, i;

  for (dark_pixels = 0, i = 0; i < img->w * img->h; ++i)
  {
    int r = img->data[(i*3)+0];
    int g = img->data[(i*3)+1];
    int b = img->data[(i*3)+2];
    if ((r+g+b)/3 < 10) { ++dark_pixels; }
  }

  return dark_pixels;

}
```

Comment: Hey Gobusto, thanks a lot for the code. Is there a name I can use for citing in my report? This is quite helpful and it's definitely a big step in the right direction.

Comment: RGB isn't the best colourspace to use

Comment: @James Why not? (Serious question - I'm not very familiar with anything other than RGB.) From your own answer I'd guess that it's because YUV has an explicit "luminance" channel, making dark pixels easier to detect?

Comment: @GoBusto - It encodes a color image or video taking human perception into account, allowing reduced bandwidth for chrominance components, thereby typically enabling transmission errors or compression artifacts to be more efficiently masked by the human perception than using a "direct" RGB-representation- from wikipedia

Answer (score 0):

Uncompress the jpeg, get the Y channel pixel data (these values are the luminosity of each pixel), count the dark pixels in that. I don't think you need the U and V channels, these are used to reconstruct the colour information.

Working RGB may be a pain, but it all depends on what you mean by a 'dark' pixel.

Comment: To be quite honest, I am not well read on color theory. I am taking in an image with a webcam and I need to separate the bright background from the object. I need to find the area of the object from the top view to categorize it. I wasn't aware there was a luminosity channel. It's a good tip, is there an example somewhere that you can point me to?

Comment: @Klik http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YUV

Answer (score 0):

JPEG images are usually encoded using the YCbCr color space. Rather than Red, Green, Blue the three components are Darkness, Blueness, and redness. The Y component is then a black and white version of the color image.

You can then determine the darkness of any point by examining the value of the Y component of the image. You can set some threshold to determine a dark pixel.